# UIToolbar doesn't fit the screen

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, autolayout, uitoolbar

I made a a custom keyboard toolBar:

[image]

To do that I created a toolbar

```
let keyboardToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44))
```

and a view for the banner

```
adToolbar = GADBannerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44))
```

then I grouped them in another UIToolbar (I tried UIView too)

```
let clusterView = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 88))
clusterView.addSubview(adToolbar)
clusterView.addSubview(keyboardToolbar)
```

and I added the view to the UITextField's keyboard.

Everything ok, but when I rotate the device happens this:

[image: clusterView UIToolbar resize correctly but not the two contained bars...]
(clusterView UIToolbar resize correctly but not the two contained bars...)

I tried with

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    methodWhichGeneratesToolbar() 
}
```

But it's the same, what can I try to solve this issue?

[P.S.: I've made an example project.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4712155/UIToolbar%20doesn%27t%20fit%20the%20screen.zip)

Comment: Have you tried using programmatic autolayout?

Comment: Nope, honestly I've never studied autolayout by code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion on how to do it with programmatic autolayout using Visual Format Language (VFL). You'll need to have a look at [the VFL docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html) to understand the VFL string syntax (They are pinning the outer view to the top and sides of the main view, and pinning the two subviews inside and to each other, and setting their height to 44).

I don't have AdMob installed, so I used a regular UIView instead of the banner view, but hopefully it should resize similarly - this code works ok on the 9.2 simulator in a test app

```
let keyboardToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44))
keyboardToolbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false //This is critical for all programmatic autolayout - if you forget it nothing will work


let adToolbar = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44))
adToolbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


let clusterView = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 88))
clusterView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

//Map views to keys used in visual format language strings
let views = ["keyboardToolbar":keyboardToolbar,"adToolbar":adToolbar,"clusterView":clusterView]

//Map values to strings used in vfl strings
let metrics = ["barHeight":44]

//In named variables to make it clear what they are
//Syntax is explained in link above
let verticalConstraintsStr = "V:|[keyboardToolbar(barHeight)][adToolbar(barHeight)]|"
let adHorizontalConstraintsStr = "|[adToolbar]|"
let keyboardHorizontalConstraintsStr = "|[keyboardToolbar]|"

let subViewConstraintStrs = [
  verticalConstraintsStr,
  adHorizontalConstraintsStr,
  keyboardHorizontalConstraintsStr
]


//Views must be added to subviews before adding constraints
// if the superview is referenced using
//the | symbol in the VFL strings

clusterView.addSubview(keyboardToolbar)
clusterView.addSubview(adToolbar)

//Converts strings to constraints for subviews and add them

for constraintStr in subViewConstraintStrs {
  let allConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(constraintStr, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: metrics, views: views) 
  clusterView.addConstraints(allConstraints)

}

let clusterVerticalConstraintsStr = "V:|[clusterView]" //Note no | at the end - no bottom pin
let clusterHorizontalConstraintsStr = "|[clusterView]|"

view.addSubview(clusterView)

//Same process for the enclosing view

for constraintStr in [clusterVerticalConstraintsStr,clusterHorizontalConstraintsStr] {
        let allConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(constraintStr, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: metrics, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(allConstraints)
    }
```

VFL is powerful but annoying to debug, and can't do all types of constraint (e.g. not alignments - you have to use an even more verbose API for those).

Comment: I update the code as I implemented it and it works great! ...I shall study VFL... thank you very much!